# mod of a number with a really long exponent

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, totient-function

How would I go about calculating this quickly without a calculator?

$| 157^{888888888888888888889} | \mod(15) $

I don't see a way to use small fermat theorem.

Eulers thing leaves me with the big number $\mod(8)$. Not that much easier.

dividing the thing up still leaves me with an array of 1s..

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you calculate modulo $3$ and then modulo $5$ you will know the answer for $15$. Little Fermat helps with those. If you ask more questions here please use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** That big number $\mod 8$ is absurdly easy to calculate.

Comment: Thanks. Am retarded.

Answer (score 2):

"Euler's thing" $\phi(15) = 8$

A really big number mod 8

$888888888889\equiv 1\pmod 8$

And off the top we can say
$157^k \equiv 7^k\pmod {15}$

Where are we?

$15^{888888888889}\equiv 7^1\pmod {15}$